# invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression error with ChromeDriver and Chrome using Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, invalidselectorexception

I am currently facing a problem with Selenium and findElements(By.xpath()).

Currently I am automating on Salesforce (dynamic IDs and we are using text() so we cannot use CSS selectors) and while my XpathFinder (Chrome AddOn) is able to process the Xpath Selenium throws the following error:

```
    invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression 

//div[contains(@class,'windowViewMode-normal')]//div[@class='slds-tabs_default' and not(ancestor::* 
     [contains(@class,'sidebar')])]//force-record-layout-item//(span[not(contains(@class,'assistive') 
     or @class='slds-checkbox' or contains(@class,'slds-button') or contains(@class,'test-id__field- 
     value') or contains(@class,'flex-wrap') or contains(@class,'avatar'))]|a|emailui-formatted-email- 
     wrapper//div[not(*)]|lightning-formatted-text|lightning-formatted-number[text()]|lightning- 
     formatted-name|lightning-formatted-phone[not(*)]|lightning-formatted-address[not(*)]) 
because of the following error:
    SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 
    '//div[contains(@class,'windowViewMode-normal')]//div[@class='slds-tabs_default' and 
    not(ancestor::*[contains(@class,'sidebar')])]//force-record-layout-                
    item//(span[not(contains(@class,'assistive') or @class='slds-checkbox' or contains(@class,'slds- 
    button') or contains(@class,'test-id__field-value') or contains(@class,'flex-wrap') or 
    contains(@class,'avatar'))]|a|emailui-formatted-email-wrapper//div[not(*)]|lightning-formatted- 
    text|lightning-formatted-number[text()]|lightning-formatted-name|lightning-formatted- 
    phone[not(*)]|lightning-formatted-address[not(*)])' 
is not a valid XPath expression.
(Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),
platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

The problem is in the grouping after

```
//div[contains(@class,'windowViewMode-normal')]//div[@class='slds-tabs_default' and not(ancestor::* 
 [contains(@class,'sidebar')])]//force-record-layout-item//...
```

If i remove the grouping (the ( before the first span and ) at the end of the xpath) and add that part of the xpath after every | the xpath can be evaluated by both XpathFinder and Selenium.

Is my grouping wrong and the browser is just coincidentlly able to evaluate this or is Selenium buggy while evaluating xpaths?

So to summerize it simply:

If i try to evaluate the following

```
//div//(a|b)
```

the evaluation failed with the given error. Is the grouping done wrong or am I missing something else?

**EDIT:**

After getting ChromeDriver to v79 to match the versions the same error appeared:

```
invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression 

(//div[contains(@class,'windowViewMode-normal')]//div[@class='slds- 
tabs_default' and not(ancestor::*[contains(@class,'sidebar')])]//force-record- 
layout-item)//(span[not(contains(@class,'assistive') or @class='slds-checkbox' 
or contains(@class,'slds-button') or contains(@class,'test-id__field-value') or 
contains(@class,'flex-wrap') or contains(@class,'avatar'))]|a|emailui- 
formatted-email-wrapper//div[not(*)]|lightning-formatted-text|lightning- 
formatted-number[text()]|lightning-formatted-name|lightning-formatted- 
phone[not(*)]|lightning-formatted-address[not(*)]) 

because of the following error:

SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string  

'(//div[contains(@class,'windowViewMode-normal')]//div[@class='slds- 
tabs_default' and not(ancestor::*[contains(@class,'sidebar')])]//force-record- 
layout-item)//(span[not(contains(@class,'assistive') or @class='slds-checkbox' 
or contains(@class,'slds-button') or contains(@class,'test-id__field-value') or 
contains(@class,'flex-wrap') or contains(@class,'avatar'))]|a|emailui- 
formatted-email-wrapper//div[not(*)]|lightning-formatted-text|lightning- 
formatted-number[text()]|lightning-formatted-name|lightning-formatted- 
phone[not(*)]|lightning-formatted-address[not(*)])' is not a valid XPath 
expression.
(Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB is the last portion I add better? Should i exclude the specific xpaths in the error message? I just wanted to mention that I am working in Salesforce before I receive some messages saying to use By.id or CSS selectors

Comment: This seems like a really overly complicated XPath. Can you post some of the relevant HTML and describe what you are trying to locate? Maybe we can come up with a better locator that will work and make your life a LOT easier... :)

Comment: @JeffC If you are able to make it any less complicated I would love to receive some tips. I am searching for multiple fields (labels and values) in one page. Unfortunally the formatting of the HTML file is shitty but that was the maximum I could do.
https://pastebin.com/hHUDqn6D
I copied one <div> above my searched one to have the siblings of my div included. Basically what i am searching for are field labels (mostly <span>) and field values (<span>,<a>,<lightning-formatted-number/text/date/..) there are some field values which are empty but I need them too to check if it really should be.

Comment: I see the pastebin... give me a couple examples of what you are looking for, e.g. the dollar amount next to "Total:" or whatever.

Comment: Well basically i am reading every field label and field value of that salesforce object which you can see in the screenshot:
https://pasteboard.co/IQ6D9nL.png

Comment: I am doing that to verify our middleware is encrypting/decrypting the values correctly thus I am building a map of field labels and their values and compare the resulting list to a JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression 

//div[contains(@class,'windowViewMode-normal')]...lightning-formatted-address[not(*)])' 
is not a valid XPath expression.
(Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),
platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to locate an element due to [invalid selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49908244/message-org-openqa-selenium-invalidselectorexception-invalid-selector-unable/49909051#49909051).

---

If you observe the intermediate `<span>` tag within the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) you are using, there seems an extra pair of single quotes present which is causing [InvalidSelectorException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55919620/send-whatsapp-message-to-contacts-using-python-but-getting-an-error-invalidsele/55919967#55919967):

```
//(span[not(contains(@class,'assistive') or @class='slds-checkbox' or contains(@class,'slds-button') or contains(@class,'test-id__field-value') or contains(@class,'flex-wrap') or contains(@class,'avatar'))]                                                                                  
  ^starting here
```

Removing this will solve your issue of [invalid selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50003307/invalidselectorerror-invalid-selector-unable-to-locate-an-element-with-the-xpa/50005362#50005362)

---

However your bigger issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.41*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.41*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v67-69**

- You are using *chrome=79.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v79.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 79**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *unknown* to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.41* and the *Chrome Browser v79.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: I did not downvote but upvoted just now because of the information regarding the versions (so you are up to 0 again). Unfortunally the upgrade of the chromedriver to v79 did not fix the issue. I am getting the exact same error message as above.

Comment: @Aleks Can you update the question with a fresh set of error trace/logs so we can have a relook please?

Comment: @Aleks Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Unfortunally there are no excessive quotes anywhere to be found. The bracket '(' at the above mentioned span is implying the coming group of span | a | lightning-formatted-text | ...

Comment: Can you update the question with the text based relevant HTML?

Comment: It is not site specific. If i go to https://www.google.com and try to get the web elements with the following xpath "//div//(span|a)" it throws the same error.

Comment: Version mismatch is not the issue or the browser would not have even navigated to the page at the start of the test. The problem is clearly stated in the error message, "... is not a valid XPath expression".