# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression is invalid using xpath within scrollIntoView through Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, xpath, js-scrollintoview, execute-script

I use Python to **scrape** a website with a filter pane that needs to be scrolled.
I found a code that helps to scroll through the list of elements, that actually find a list and move through a loop.

```js
recentList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/fieldset[3]/div/ul/li")
for list in recentList:
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest"})', list)
```

I have code that already contains a for loop and I would like to add only an element that needs to be scrolled to.
With the logic of the above I've written (a loop is simplified):

```js
for p in range(1,15):
    list = driver.find_element_by_xpath(str('/html/body/div[3]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/fieldset[3]/div/ul/li[[' + str(p) + ']'))
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest"})', list)
```

I can't figure out why it doesn't work.
Here is an Error I got:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "/html/body/div[3]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/fieldset[3]/div/ul/li[[1]" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
```

Does anyone know what needs to be fixed?
The XPath in the last code is correct and was already in use.

I tried to replace my current loop with the "list in recentList" but then code stops when it needs to scroll through pages on a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "/html/body/div[3]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/fieldset[3]/div/ul/li[[1]" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
```

...implies that the *XPath* expression was not a valid/legal expression.

If you observe the effective [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) within the error, there is an extra third bracket opening within the expression:

```
/html/body/div[3]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/fieldset[3]/div/ul/li[[1]
```

---

### Solution

To remove the extra third bracket opening, you need to adjust the *xpath expression* as:

```js
list = driver.find_element_by_xpath(str('/html/body/div[3]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/fieldset[3]/div/ul/li[' + str(p) + ']'))
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50003307/invalidselectorerror-invalid-selector-unable-to-locate-an-element-with-the-xpa/50005362#50005362)
- [Message “org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the XPath expression” using sendKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49908244/message-org-openqa-selenium-invalidselectorexception-invalid-selector-unable/49909051#49909051)
- [Send whatsapp message to contacts using Python but getting an error: InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55919620/send-whatsapp-message-to-contacts-using-python-but-getting-an-error-invalidsele/55919967#55919967)

Comment: Thank you! That's really awkward. I checked a text 3 times letter by letter, I don't know how I could miss it.